# Syntax directed definition (count number of pairs of parentheses)

Tags: syntax, grammar, parse-tree

given the following grammar I have to find the appropriate semantic actions to calculate, for each string of the language, the number of pairs of parentheses in the string.

**S -> (L)**

**S -> a**

**L -> L, S**

**L -> S**

Usually, to perform this type of exercise, I build a derivation tree of a sample string and then I add the attributes. After that it is easier to find the semantic rules.

So I built this derivation tree for the string "**((a, (a), a))**", but I can't proceed with the resolution of the exercise. How do I count the pairs of parentheses? I'am not able to do that...

[image]

I do't want the solution but I'd like someone to help me with the reasoning to be made in these cases.

(I'm sorry for the bad tree...)

Comment: This isn't clear.  If you have the tree, what is the problem with counting the number of parentheses?

Comment: Since the pairing of parameters is handled by the grammar itself, it seems you can just attach a counting semantic action to the match for right-paren (or left, for that matter).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Hi Oliver, thank's for the reply. A logic I would say that the structure of the attributes must be made with a counter that is updated every time you find a pair of parentheses. But where to initialize the counter? How do I upgrade? For example, in the production **L -> S** what is the attribute? I do't put anyone, there are no brackets .. but it seems strange. Is there anything that stops me in this type of exercise where you have to count the occurrences of something...

Comment: @500-InternalServerError For example I can add to the rule S -> (L) the semantic action **S.p = 1+ counter**. But how and where I initialize the counter? And the other productions they just carry around this value?

Comment: The counter will be held at the global level and initialized to zero before you invoke the parser. The semantic action attached to the match for either `)` or `(` will simply be `counter++`.

Answer (score 0):

The OP wrote:

> These might be the correct semantic actions for this grammar?
>
> **S -> (L)** {S.p = counter + 1}
>
> **S -> a** {do nothing}
>
> **L -> L, S** {L.p = S.p}
>
> **L -> S** {L.p = S.p}
>
> .p is a synthesized attribute.

Comment: ([Answered in a question edit and converted to a community wiki answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que)).

Answer (score 0):

```
S-> (S)     { S.count =S.count + 1} 
S-> SS{ S.count  = S.count + S.count}
S-> ϵ{S.count = 0}
```

This should make things clear